# How to combine regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following function which validates date formats in two main formats: with and without separators.

```
function check_date_format (my_date) {

    var regex = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{2})$/; //Declare regex for date with separators
    var date_array = my_date.match(regex);

    if (date_array == null) {
        regex = /^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/; //Declare regex for date without separators
        date_array = my_date.match(regex);

        if (date_array == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The first `.match(regex)` returns an array of 5 elemnts for: day (1 or 2 digits), first separator (- or /), month (1 or 2 digits), second separator (- or / can be different from first separator) and year (2 digits).

The second `.match(regex)` returns an array of 3 elements for: day (2 digits), month (2 digits) and year (2 digits).

I tried to merge the two with this regex:

```
/^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{2})$|^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/
```

And the validation works but `my_date` becomes an array of 8 cells where the first 5 or the last 3 will be undefined depending on which part of the regex matches the pattern.

Is there a way of merging the two sections and only return an array with either 5 or 3 cells depending on which part was matched?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fabricis/LQrnZ/) for testing several date formats and the merged and split regexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should do what you want:

```
/^(\d{1,2})([\/-]?)(\d{1,2})\2(\d{2})$/
```

Day, month, year are in capturing group 1, 3, 4 respectively.

I use backreference **`\2`** to make sure that the second separator (between year and month) is the same as the first separator captured in capturing group **2** `([\/-]?)`. Therefore, it is slightly different from your code: it doesn't accept inputs with mixed separators such as `12/3-01`.

Comment: And if you remove the brackets around the separators, they will not form matching groups in the result.

Comment: @CompuChip: What are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your edit about using the backref to make sure the separators match. In that case you need them anyway. Originally I meant, you can remove the surrounding `()` from `([\/-]?)` then you will get an array with only (day, month, year) regardless of the presence of the separator.

Comment: Cool guys! Thanks a lot. I prefer the option with the *\2*. It has a side effect I can live with though... :-) The array now has always 4 elements where the 1st, 3rd and 4th are numbers and the 2nd is either the separator (- or /) or an empty string.